# How to rewrite the surface integral $\int_{(s_1,\ldots,s_n) \in \mathbb S_{n-1}}\sqrt{1-s_1^2}ds$ as a special function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, special-functions, surface-integrals

Let $n \ge 2$ be an integer and let $\mathbb S_{n-1}$ be the $(n-1)$-dimensional unit-sphere.

> **Question.** How to rewrite the surface  integral $I_n:= \int_{(s_1,\ldots,s_n) \in \mathbb S_{n-1}}\sqrt{1-s_1^2}ds$ as a special function ?

Note that $I_n = 2\sigma_nh_n$, where $\sigma_n$ is the surface area of $\mathbb S_{n-1}$ and $h_n$ is the average "co-height" of a point a hemisphere, sampled according to the uniform measure on $\mathbb S_{n-1}$.

Comment: Change to hyperspherical coordinates and show that
$$\int_0^\pi \sqrt {1 - \cos^2 \theta} \sin^{n - 2} \theta \, d\theta =
B {\left( \frac n 2, \frac 1 2 \right)}.$$
The integral over the remaining spherical angles is the surface area of a lower-dimensional sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So, If i read you well, this would ultimately yield $I_n = \sigma_{n-2} B(n/2,1/2)$, where $\sigma_{n-2}$ is the surface area of the $(n-2)$-dimensional unit-sphere, right ?

Comment: That is correct.